# How to get one random entry from among multiple sections

Tags: templating, entries, sections

I'm trying to pull a random entry from among an array of sections, but I can't get it to work.

I tried the code below, but I'm just getting errors. I've tried multiple ways of listing the sections -- "section","section" ['section,section'],etc, but none work. Do I need to specify my sections in a different way?

```
{% set random = craft.entries.section('quotes,didYouKnow').limit(1).order('RAND()').find() %}
{% for content in random %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/craft.entries.html#parameters), you can **pass an array** into the "section" parameter:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['quotes','didYouKnow']) %}
```

There are several ways to get a random entry, but the method you've chosen is a very good one, because it randomizes during the initial SQL call:

```
.order('RAND()')
```

Lastly, you can cut out some of the extra legwork from your original example by calling `first` instead of `find`:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('mySection').first() %}
```

When you retrieve your entry using `first`, you'll get a single entry instead of an array of entries. You can skip the `for` loop entirely, since you're already dealing with a single entry.

**So to put that all together...**

```
{% set randomEntry = craft.entries.section(['quotes','didYouKnow']).order('RAND()').first() %}

<h1>{{ randomEntry.title }}</h1>
```

Comment: Would in this case other filters e.g `postDate desc` work?

Comment: Other filters work a little differently... here is a good example of [using multiple search filters on the `postDate` field...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2875/45)