# How to filter entries by month and year?

Tags: postdate

I'm taking the month and year from parameters in the url like this...

```
{% set month = craft.request.getParam('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.getParam('year')  %}
```

The url would look like this: ?month=September&Year=2014

... and want to return entries from a specific section where the postDate month and year match those parameters.

Be very grateful for any pointers.

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this (not tested):

```
{% set month = craft.request.getParam('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.getParam('year')  %}

{% set firstDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth = now | date_modify('last day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSection').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, your code worked and taught me something new.