# Filter entries by month

Tags: entries, postdate, archives

I'm trying to make a archive page for a blog sorted by months. I tried to consult the solution from [Linking and showing archive by month](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/linking-and-showing-archive-by-month), but I can't get it to work like it should. The code I have now just displays all entries regardless of their post date.

```
{% set catch = year ~ '-' ~ month ~ '-01' %}
{% set firstDay = catch | date_modify('first day of ', month ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set lastDay = catch | date_modify('last day of ', month ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}
{% set archive  = craft.entries.section('blog').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDay.date, '<= ' ~ lastDay.date) %}
{% for entry in archive %}
    <div class="posts-block">
        <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I had to add ".date" behind "firstDay" and "lastDay", or I get an error (Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string) If I remove the "and" from "archive" like this:

```
{% set archive  = craft.entries.section('blog').postDate('>= ' ~ firstDay.date, '<= ' ~ lastDay.date) %}
```

then it sorts my entries according to "firstDay", but completely ignores "lastDay". I tried to threw an and into the middle of the string, but that didn't to anything.

I also tried to use .after and .before, but then I just get what seems like a random set of entries...

```
{% set archive = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null).after(firstDay).before(lastDay) %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value you need to set the `postDate` parameter to is quite complex. If you define a dedicated variable for it, it makes the code more readable and you can more easily debug the value using the `dump()` function.

For the problem itself, you were on the right track. The main problem is a syntax mistake, you are passing in the `'and', '>= ', ...` values without wrapping them as an array.

Some other changes I’d suggest is to use the `<` operator in combination with a relative time of `'first day of next month'`, so every entry before 00:00 of that day (see documentation of [relative date/time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)).

And instead of the `.date` property, I'd rather use the `date` filter to output the DateTime object as a string in the right format. Which can be `'Y-m-d'` to omit the time completely (Craft sets it back to 00:00), or one of the characters that output a full date with time `'c'` or `'U'` (see documentation of [date format parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

```
{% set firstDay = date(year ~ '-' ~ month ~ '-01') %}
{% set lastDay = firstDay|date_modify('first day of next month') %}

{% set postDateParam = ['and', '>= ' ~ firstDay|date('c'), '< ' ~ lastDay|date('c')] %}

<pre>{{ dump(postDateParam) }}</pre>

{% set archive = craft.entries({
    section: 'blog',
    postDate: postDateParam,
}) %}
```

Comment: This works and was easy to understand, thank you so much!

Comment: I had the same doubt.
Thank you very much.