# Archiving by month and year - timezone could not be found error

Tags: datetime, archives, timezone

Following the answer in this thread -[Linking and showing archive by month](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/linking-and-showing-archive-by-month)  by P&T has worked fine for previous sites but now I'm getting the following error. I've checked I have a Time zone selected in System settings.

```
DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (first day of archive 
2018 00:00:00) at position 13 (a): The timezone could not be found in 
the database
```

Template:

```
{% set month = craft.request.segment(3) %}
{% set year = craft.request.segment(4) %}

{% set firstDay = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 00:00:00') %}
{% set lastDay = now | date_modify('last day of ' ~ month ~ ' ' ~ year ~ ' 23:59:59') %}

{% set archive  = craft.entries.section('bulletinOnline').postDate('and', '>= ' ~ firstDay, '<= ' ~ lastDay) %}

{% for entry in archive %}  

  ...

{% endfor %}
```